# How can I find the derivative G'(x) of this function?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I'm not sure how to do this question because there is another variable t inside it.
[image]

Find G'(x).

Comment: Have you heard of the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Isn't it when : F(b)-F(a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem if $G(x) = \int_0^x g(t) \; dt$, then $G'(X) = g(x)$. Therefore you fill find that $G'(x) = -\cos \sqrt[5]{x}$.

Comment: Why would it be -cos?

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the other posted answer, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we may say that if $G(x) = \int_{\xi_1(x)} ^{\xi_2 (x)} g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t$, then 
$$
G'(x) = g(\xi _2 (x)) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} \xi_2 (x)}{\mathrm{d} x} - g(\xi _1 (x)) \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} \xi_1 (x)}{\mathrm{d} x}
. 
$$
This follows from applying the chain rule to the anti-derivative, or primitive function, of $g(t)$.
Then, for this specific question, $\xi_2$ is a constant function so that its derivative is 0, and $\xi_1 (x) = x$ so that $\xi_1 ' (x) = 1$. Then, 
$$
G'(x) = - \cos \sqrt[5]{x} \cdot 1 = - \cos \sqrt[5]{x}
.
$$